# A deadly turn to common things

Tags: riddle

I'm known to make memories, to help preserve the past.
But have you considered a turn to that statement?
One click out of me, and you've shot who's in front of me.
Though used to prevent, I can cause lament.

I'm much deadlier than most weapons, who says I can only shoot people?
The click doesn't just mean a shot, it can also decapitate.
I keep memories of people, after making them a memory.
You can also throw me, but to do so would need lots of hate.

I'm very common, you see. You never know, you're surrounded by me.
I'm able to shoot or behead anyone, but I'm still allowed on a plane.
It's possible that one is looking at you now, ready to click.
Covering your face can save you, but you might be called insane.

Who or what am I?

> Look at the title. You might find this riddle funny when you understand where I'm coming from.

Comment: Just plain people?

Comment: Accurate, but no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you a

> CAMERA?

*I'm known to make memories, to help preserve the past.*

> Cameras take photos to help you preserve memories of the past.

*But have you considered a turn to that statement?*

> Not sure about the "turn" stuff.

*One click out of me, and you've shot who's in front of me.*

> A photo*shoot*, cameras click to take pictures.

*Though used to prevent, I can cause lament.*

> Not sure about "prevent", but a bad photo could cause lament.

*I'm much deadlier than most weapons, who says I can only shoot people?*

> Cameras can also take pictures of other things.

*The click doesn't just mean a shot, it can also decapitate.*

> A mugshot photo that only shows someone's head without their body?

*I keep memories of people, after making them a memory.*

> Even after someone has died, photos can preserve them in memory.

*You can also throw me, but to do so would need lots of hate.*

> Throwing a camera and breaking it, if you're really angry.

*I'm very common, you see. You never know, you're surrounded by me.*
*I'm able to shoot or behead anyone, but I'm still allowed on a plane.*
*It's possible that one is looking at you now, ready to click.*
*Covering your face can save you, but you might be called insane.*

> In the modern world, CCTV and phone cameras are everywhere, even on planes, taking pictures of anyone at any time, and you can't cover your face all the time.

Comment: Yep! Gotta wait a few minutes to accept it, though. I was hoping some of the other red herrings would lead people away, but this was fun to write.

Comment: By the way people also fits the description. Is it okay if I post that answer?

Comment: @zixuan Sure, competing answers are fine. I'll be interested to see how "people" fits as an answer, since I can't see it myself.

Comment: I posted mine too

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't fit that much with the clues, but

> People?

I'm able to make memories, to help preserve the past

> People make paintings and write and other ways of preserving the past

One click out of me, and you've shot who's in front of me.

> I don't see how that fits though

Though used to prevent, I can cause lament

> War?

I'm much deadlier than most weapons, who says I can only shoot people?

> People's guns can shoot other things other than people

The click doesn't just mean a shot, it can also decapitate.

> I don't know how that works?

I keep memories of people, after making them a memory.

> People keep paintings in museums?

You can also throw me, but to do so would need lots of hate.

> To throw people say, out of the window would need "lots of hate".

I'm very common, you see. You never know, you're surrounded by me.

> There are over 7.6 billion people in the world

I'm able to shoot or behead anyone, but I'm still allowed on a plane.

> People's guns can shoot and behead people, but people are still "allowed" on planes, obviously.

It's possible that one is looking at you now, ready to click.

> I don't know?

Covering your face can save you, but you might be called insane.

> There are so many people it's really hard to not expose your face?

Comment: No, not a person... look at the other answer and you'll see.

Comment: I know it's not a person, but it's a possibility. it's a worthy attempt anyway.

Comment: Think about the clicking. And yes, it's a nice attempt

Comment: "worthy of an upvote" attempt?

Comment: Sure, why not? You did hit points in ways I wasn't anticipating ;)

Comment: That wasn't me... (let's move to chat, by the way)

Comment: Sure. It doesn't really fit in. I like the red herrings used to distract

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117130/discussion-between-zixuan-and-cstafford-14).